# Some snarks are boojums: list of boojums, or is_boojum property on all snarks?

Tags: data-modeling

The problem domain features a large population of named snarks.  Some of the snarks are boojums.

There are at least two ways to model this:

```
// as a property: 
    class Snark { 
      string name; 
      bool is_boojum; 
    };  

// as a list:
    class Snark { 
      typedef long Id;
      Id id;
      string name;
    };  

    tree<Snark::Id> boojums;
```

It seems intuitive that if we determined that snarks come in male and female, we would add a "sex" property to the snark class definition; and if we determined that all but five snarks were vanquished subjects, we would make a list of royals.

Are there principles one can apply, or is it a matter of architectural preference?

Comment: Congratulations on creating the most confusing question I've seen on SO. It took me 5 reads just to *think* I know what you *might* be asking.

Comment: you need to clarify your question. i think i know what you're getting at but it's not clear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is a reference to a Lewis Carroll poem, Hunting of the Snark. Snark and Boojum are metasyntactic variables (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable), like foo and bar. A snark is an object, and boojum is an adjective that may apply to that object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the information entropy associated with the classification can be a guide to which method to use.  Low-entropy classifications (i.e. most of the objects have the same value) suggest a list implementation tracking the exceptional cases, while high-entropy classifications (you cannot make any very good predictions about which classification an object will have) suggest a property implementation.

Answer (score 6):

What problem are you trying to solve?

If the purpose of recording the royalty of the snarks is to display a crown on their heads in the GUI, then it makes sense for it to merely be an attribute. (Alternatively, there could be a RoyalSnark subclass, with an overridden Render method.)

If the purpose is to quickly find all the royal snarks, then a list is more appropriate - otherwise you would need to look at every snark and check its attribute.

Answer (score 2):

As a derived class:

```
class Snark 
{
   virtual void Approach(Creature& approacher) {};
};

class Boojum : public Snark
{
   virtual void Approach(Creature& approacher) 
   { 
      approacher.softlySuddenlyVanishAway(); 
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That natural way to do it seems to be a property in all cases.

You might use a list for performance, or to optimise space. Both reasons strike me as potential cases of premature optimisation, breaking encapsulation, and/or storing redundant data with the consequent risk of lack of integrity (because I should still be able to query the object itself to find out if it is royal - I shouldn't have to know that *this* property is handled in a special way for reasons of performance). You could I suppose hide the list implementation behind a getter, to make it behave as a property.

Also, if these objects were stored in a DB, the performance issue pretty much goes away as the DB layer can create the list at runtime using a query anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about database modeling, then it's most straightforward to treat `is_boojum` as an attribute column in the table `Snarks`.  If you need to search for all boojums, the query is simple:

```
SELECT * FROM Snarks WHERE is_boojum = 1
```

This gives logically correct answers, and it's easy to model.  It might not be so speedy, because indexing a column with low selectivity (many rows with identical values) isn't very efficient, and might not benefit from the index at all.

But your question was about modeling, not optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  My first thought is that, indeed, Boojum is a subtype of Snark.  but the specification seems to argue against it, for "the snark was a boojum, you see."  Well, that means the snark is_a Boojum, and that would make the inheritance graph cyclic.  Can't have that.

On the other hand, I do'nt think there's any indication that a Snark can *become* a Boojum; either it's a Boojum or it's not.

I think probably you want a Boojum mixin --

```
abstract class Snark { /*...*/ };
class PlainSnark extends Snark {/*...*/};
class RoyalSnark extends Snark implements Boojum {/*...*/};
```

Comment: You're reading the question differently from the other answers...

You're assuming that Boojumness is independant of Snarkness, whereas I inferred that only Snarks can be Boojums. It's not clear from the question which is right.

Also, how does "the snark was a boojum" imply "snark is_a Boojum?"?

Comment: On the Bookum-ness question, I'm referring to the original spec. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunting_of_the_Snark).  As to "was a" meaning "is a", I refer to english grammar. Boojum isn't necessarily independent; just it defines an operation ("silentlyVanish()") that other Snarks don't have.

Comment: (Yeah, I saw the spec... :-) ) I'm still not sure about the grammar aspect, though. "The car was a Ford, you see." doesn't imply that Car is_a Ford, in fact it suggests the opposite.